# How to strengthen Java ME eco-system

Tags: iphone, android, java-me

These days everyone who worked in mobile software talks about Android and iPhone.
I just wonder what is missing part from Java ME compared to these mobile software platforms.

- Open application store?
- Rich APIs?
- Compatibility?
- Big company support?

...

Do you have any idea on it? How Sun (or Oracle) can strengthen Java ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-) Pay whatever money is needed to Aplix or [Simon Lewis](http://justanapplication.wordpress.com) so that the MIDP3 reference implementation is open-sourced. Make sure phones manufacturers can get a usable open source VM to run it on.

2-) Write several proper TCKs that run real-life tests, not just cover the width of the API.

3-) Go through the existing JSRs with a fine comb to remove ambiguities and gaping holes in the specs. stop trying to make a single specification fit any possible future device.

4-) Actually enforce phone manufacturers' reponsability to ship handsets without TCK failures.

5-) Work with operators worldwide to establish clear criteria and processes for application certification.

6-) Get Nokia, Sony-Ericsson and Samsung to collaborate on J2ME instead of triplicating all their efforts.

7-) Retain an independant team of existing third-party J2ME developers, big, medium and small so they can keep you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Spolsky makes several good points about this in [podcast 57 of SO](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4144.html) as to why Windows Mobile and subsequently Java ME struggles compared to IPhone.  The hardware is VERY inconsistent and varied to the point that application design and implementation is prohibitively challenging because multiple versions of an application must be designed to support the crazy hardware variances.  IPhone is strong simply because an IPhone application ISA IPhone application because the hardware doesn't vary.  No developer is going to waste his/her time developing for multiple one-off hardware quirks that means porting the application for each phone that "runs" Java ME.

Answer (score 0):

A unified application repository/store would be nice. The [Java App Store](http://www.java.com/en/store/intl-contact.jsp) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android development is all in Java,  And Android is now pushing into multiple platforms - I would suggest the need for JavaME has sailed, at least for small consumer devices.

Small devices are now powerful enough not to need the constraints that JavaME has, designed around a lot more limited system.

There will still probably be some niche support for JavaME going forward, but I don't think you are going to see any development outside the makers of the hardware it is running on.